# How does React Loadable handle code used in multiple bundles?

Tags: webpack, react-loadable

Im doing code splitting with React Loadable in my Create React App

https://github.com/jamiebuilds/react-loadable
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app

How does React Loadable use code that is used in multiple bundles?

Say I have 2 bundles, pageA and pageB and both use a Breadcrumbs component:

PageA.js:

```
import Breadcrumbs from '../Breadcrumbs.js'
```

PageB.js:

```
import Breadcrumbs from '../Breadcrumbs.js'
```

The Breadcrumbs component must be being added to both bundles. If I visit PageA first and then navigate to PageB, is the Breadcrumbs downloaded again? Or is React Loadable / Webpack smart enough to know it already has that component downloaded in the other bundle?

Comment: Actually the right question to ask is how webpack handles async imports, `react-loadeable` just uses it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`React-loadable` is not the one that do the code splitting but your bundler (webpack and such).

You can configure webpack (not ver 4) to use [`common-chunk-split`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin/) to achieve your requirement.

With Webpack ver 4, there is an alternative to `common-chunk-split`, called `splitChunks`, you can read about it here: [webpack 4: Code Splitting, chunk graph and the splitChunks optimization](https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-4-code-splitting-chunk-graph-and-the-splitchunks-optimization-be739a861366)